# Upgrading without losing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-8.1

If we upgrade from Windows **8** to Windows **8.1**, do we need to re-install Visual Studio (any version) or any of the usual dev tools or redistributables?

I found http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-8/preview-faq but it only says "You can keep Windows Settings, personal files, and *most* apps." with no other information about which apps you can't keep.

Comment: Interesting, but does it matter? Re-installing Visual Studio isn't too onerous, and you might want the 2013 preview anyway if you don't have it already. I'd guess yes it'd probably just work though, although it might require a repair install if you're unlucky. (From a Windows 7 to 8 upgrade it's only a small set of apps on a compatibility black-list that don't work - everything else stays.)

Comment: This is a [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) question.

Comment: I don't think that VS2012 relies on a particular Windows 8 feature that would deem it unrunnable after such an update.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik thank you for your answer. I was considering asking this on SuperUser - but wasn't sure if many people over there would know about Visual Studio (since it's not really a programming-focused site).

Comment: Oh, fair enough - network installs didn't occur to me, we have all the ISOs on a server a work. Find a coffee shop that does free wifi? :-) If it was me I'd probably leave the 8.1 install until I had reliable internet again unless it was a complete blocker.

Comment: @user2645707: There're many users from Stackoverflow over there as well.

Comment: @oh awesome. Is there a way to migrate the question over or should I just delete this and re-post over there?

Comment: @Rup, next time I'm downloading the ISO. I might just wait until they fix the service but I'm gonna be totally anxious until it's fixed. I'll probably start writing code all over my walls.

Comment: You can probably flag the question for moderator attention and ask for the migration (but IMO it's fine here). You should create yourself an account in superuser first linked to your SO account so you get notifications though.

Comment: This should not be a problem. But what is the pressing need to upgrade to Windows 8.1 if you have that limited of a data allowance? Just upgrade later. You've got a working system right now.

Comment: @CodyGray I have 2 clients that want their apps updated _soon-ish_ to make use of some new stuff in Windows 8.1, and I want to update it personally as well for my own little projects.

Comment: Well, you will need the new Windows 8.1 SDK in order to develop applications that take advantage of new Windows 8.1 features. Just installing the OS will only get you part of the way there. That's going to be [another big download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx), so it's probably time to look for alternatives. Like borrowing somebody else's connection.

Comment: Regardless of my "need" to upgrade, it's still nice to know what apps can and can't be upgraded.

Comment: "...but if your question generally covers…" "software tools commonly used by programmers"  VS on Windows appears to be a valid topic for SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vistual Studio 2005 keeps working. After my upgrade to Windows 8.1 windows update, I also installed this 'Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista' by windows updates.

Afterwards I got trouble when building a .NET 2.0 project: 
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets(1960,9):
   error MSB3011: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\AL.exe"
   was not found. Either 1) Install the .NET Framework SDK, which will
   install AL.exe. Or 2) Pass the correct location of AL.exe into the
   "ToolPath" parameter of the AL task.

I just copied these files manually from a old backup and now it builds. So far so good. If any more trouble occurres I'll just remove the VS2005 and install is again.

Upgrading to Windows 8.1 went pretty smooth!

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 6 (we have some VB6 apps and Excel add ins we have been unable to migrate), Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2010 installed. After the upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1, running VB6 caused the installer to pop up and it went and spent quite a while configuring "Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional". Fortunately we had the installation on a network location and it completed successfully. Seems to work fine after that.

I have had a few issues with Windows 8.1 such as the sentinel drivers for AQTime not supporting 8.1.